# How can some third-party services allow you to send WhatsApp messages to a group when the official API doesn't permit it?

Tags: whatsapp, whatsapp-cloud-api

After exploring the WhatsApp official API for the first time and reading some posts on StackOverflow, I noticed that it seems no longer possible (as it apparently was until 2020) to send WhatsApp messages to a group via the official API. However, I found several third-party services that enable this functionality (for example, I successfully tried and managed to send messages to an ad hoc group I created using Maytapi).
I have noticed that all of these services ask you to "pair" your whatsapp account with their system, differently from the official whatsapp api that, at least while testing, supplies you a dedicated phone number.
So, I'm assuming these services can 'simulate' your WhatsApp account, allowing API usage as if it's being done directly from the app or web app.
I wonder if anyone has more information about this and can share it. Thank you.

Comment: That's right, these services are called unofficial services. They create another connection to your WhatsApp by emulating a browser / or via sockets (i.e. you give this service access to your WhatsApp). This way they can automate any functionality that Meta does not provide. Of course, this carries the risks of both leaking your information and being blocked by Meta). So in this case, either do not use such services or connect a non-personal phone number.

Comment: @Hafiz thank you! Have you any hint maybe on how to start to emulate by myself my whatsapp account?